# Why NoMethodError does not show an exception in development env?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Rails app which produce the exception:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass)
```

This error is only shown in strout. The app continue without showing any indication of an error.

How can I configure Rails to show this exception in the web page instead of being thrown at the console only?

Comment: Are you rescuing `StandardError` or `Exception` somewhere?

Comment: Yes. But we send the error to Raven, which is not enabled in dev env.

Comment: Perhaps you should show what that rescue block looks like? It might be swallowing your error.